# What's the optimal way to deal with non-existent variables in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails app that pulls data in from Groupon's API and displays them on our site.

Take the follow data structure, for example:

```
---
- "id": deal one
  "options": 
    "redemptionLocations": 
    - "streetAddress1": 123 Any Street"

- "id": deal two
  "options": []
```

If I wanted to loop through each deal, and display the streetAddress1 if it exists, what's the optimal way to do that in Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
if(defined? streetAddress1) then
    print streetAddress1 + " is set"
end
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The best practice should be to use `present?`:

```
puts "It is #{object.attribute}" if object.attribute.present?
```

If you have an array of objects and want to loop only over those that have the attribute set, you can use `select`:

```
array.select{|object| object.attribute.present?}.each do |object|
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks David. I think that, because of the deepness of the data structure, I'm getting this error: NoMethodError: undefined method `streetAddress1' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

If you have a deeply nested structure you can create a custom function to check if a key exists and display its value:

```
def nested_value hash, *args
  tmp = hash
  args.each do |arg|
    return nil if tmp.nil? || !tmp.respond_to?(:[]) || (tmp.is_a?(Array) && !arg.is_a?(Integer))
    tmp = tmp[arg]
  end
  tmp
end
```

For example, if you have the following YAML loaded from your example:

```
k = [
  { "id"=>"deal one",
    "options"=>{"redemptionLocations"=>[{"streetAddress1"=>"123 Any Street\""}]}},
  { "id"=>"deal two",
    "options"=>[]}]
```

Then you can do this:

```
nested_value k.first, 'options', 'redemptionLocations', 0, 'streetAddress1'
=> "123 Any Street \""
nested_value k.last, 'options', 'redemptionLocations', 0, 'streetAddress1'
=> nil
```